# ¿como saber la longitud de un wchar_t en c++?

Tags: c++, unicode

Para usar una función necesito saber cual es el número de letras que hay en una variable de tipo `wchar_t`. El problema es que no me deja usar `strlen` ni `sizeof` asique como alternativa he creado un objeto de tipo `wstring` lo igualo a la variable `wchar_t` y después uso sobre el objeto el método `length()`:

```
wstring objeto;
wchar_t inter[80];

char aux[80];
size_t tamaño = 0;

//... (se le da un valor a inter)

objeto = inter;
wcstombs_s(&tamaño, aux,inter,objeto.length()); // aqui es donde me hace falta la longitud de inter
```

Si lo uso así funciona pero quería saber si hay alguna función que pueda hacerlo en un solo paso y no complique tanto las cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `wchar_t` no tiene *longitud*, pero puedes averiguar su tamaño con `sizeof`:

```
// Imprime 2 en windows, 4 en linux (16 y 32 bits respectivamente)
std::cout << sizeof(wchar_t) << '\n';
```

Ahora bien, si quieres saber la longitud de una cadena de caracteres codificada con `wchar_t` entonces la cosa se complica; en general basta con saber cuántos elementos tiene la cadena y asumir que cada elemento corresponde a una letra:

```
std::wstring hola = L"Hola!";
std::cout << hola.length(); // Muestra 5
```

Pero si se está utilizando una codificación multibyte, entonces [la cosa puede no cuadrar](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JVXBJjO/uKQoNTHXjgshBhTJzEu34@LKzCtRyE3MzNPQ5Krm4iwuSbGyKodIKiQq2Cr4KD2aueDRzKWPZi57NHPxh/nN/UrWUGVQVUlAVbgVJeeXlnBxctrYKCTq5aTmpZdkaGgqAHnqMXnqEPEkuDhQT1FqSWlRnoKBNVft//8A):

```
std::wstring a = L"♠♥♦♣";
std::string b = "♠♥♦♣";
std::cout
    << a.length() << '\n'   // Debería mostrar 5
    << b.length();          // Debería mostrar 5, muestra 16
```

Para la mayoría de casos no tendrás problema alguno asumiendo que la cantidad de elementos de un `std::wstring` equivale a la cantidad de caracteres, a no ser que mezcles codificaciones, así que no las mezcles.